# BoilerplateJS and Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, boilerplatejs

wondering how to use BoilerplateJS with Jquery Mobile. Perticulary when it comes to manage url and how to deal with the  which is created automatically. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any examples out there so have been doing exactly that myself but haven't yet completed the exercise. You need to add the jQuery Mobile references into the top level index.html and then modify the html (structure, tags) to something that JQM will like to render. You also need to ensure the views correctly trigger enhancement of content changes. It seems straight forward enough although styling might yet be a gotcha so I can't yet say whether it's trivial-but-time-consuming or going to be a mess.